# событие onInput не берет в расчет после точки

Tags: javascript, c#, input

- Blazor Server Side

я использую событие `oninput` в моем `input`, а в label показываю вычисление +/-

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

30-28.5 = 1.5, а выдает 2 (не берет в расчет, то, что после точки/запятой)

пробовала использовать [onfocusout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocusout.asp) (подумала, может когда я выйду за поле, он тогда перерасчет возьмет полностью ) тот же результат

```
<input step="any" min="0" type="number" @bind-value=@myModel.ValueBase
       onclick="this.select();" @oninput="@((args)=>InputBind(args, myDataObject))"
       class="someCss" />

<label style="visibility:@someVisibility;">
    (@string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:F3}", @ValueUpdate))
</label>
```

```
float ValueUpdate;
public void InputBind(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ChangeEventArgs args, MyModel model)
{
    float intOut;
    if (float.TryParse(args.Value.ToString(), out intOut))
    {
        ValueUpdate = intOut;
    }

    ValueUpdate = ValueUpdate - model.ValueBase; // model.ValueBase type float
}
```

может мой string format неверный ? а может там output  в стринг когда идет, надо обратно во float, или может вообще не так все делать ?

Comment: Не может ли быть так, что тип ValueUpdate является int?

Comment: @XelaNimed все типы float https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWZKU.png еще раз и по коду параноически проверила, думала об этом, что может типа когда я пишу =float.TryParse(args.Value.ToString(), out intOut) оно че то там делает и мне инт возвращает...

Comment: В таком случае попробуйте явно установить шаг (step) в input, например в 0.1.

Comment: так же тут была https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011861/is-there-a-float-input-type-in-html5 и поэтому добавила step="any"

Comment: @XelaNimed ой одновременно), да, я и так тоже пробовала и там же читала, что типа any работает

Comment: Попробуйте изменить step с any на 0.1 и вводить не с клавиатуры, а с помощью стрелок вверх/вниз. В таком случае Вы также увидите какой разделитель используется - точка или запятая, т.к. вполне может статься, что Вы используете некорректный для текущей локали разделитель.

Comment: @XelaNimed ыЫ https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5FkG.png, а как это исправить, я даже не знаю как новый вопрос задать, типа как float во float ? ===> насколько я поняла основное поле с запятой, а коррекция с точкой, и там происходит конфликт. Странно, что я пыталась и так и так вводить (те и с точкой вводила и с запятой, просто видимо тк у них изначально разный формат они конфликтуют)

Comment: [Похожая проблема](https://stackoverflow.com/q/793459/3129992)

Comment: исправила label на input https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzpCc.png те дело наверно не в этом ? по ссылке выше ходила, там предлагают локализацию указать, свой контрол создали, в блазор все почти встроено, локализация верная установленна

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 30-28.5 = 1.5, а выдает 2

Тебе нужно смотреть что в итоге у тебя получается на клиенте. Вот смотри - все работает

```js
test.addEventListener('input', e => {
  const v = +e.target.value
  res.innerText = 30 - v
})
```

```html
<input id='test' type='number' />
<p>(<span id='res'></span>)</p>
```

Comment: и правда работает у вас, хочу, чтоб у меня тоже работало, а где тогда я упускаю, вот сравниваю и вроде так же все => (вот ваше const v = +e.target.value)  => (мое =>ValueUpdate = intOut; (где intOut и есть выход клиента ?)

Answer (score 0):

источник отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/a/63880070/13754729

решение мне не нравится (почему надо полю давать значение text если я цифру пишу, те надо еще запретить вводить буквы), но работает, поэтому оставлю здесь, если кто как и я искал ...

```
 <input step="any" min="0" type="text" inputmode="decimal" @bind-value=@myModel.ValueBase
        onclick="this.select();" @oninput="@((args)=>InputBind(args, myDataObject))"
       class="someCss" />

 <input style="visibility:@someVisibility;" @bind-value="@ValueUpdate">
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]